# bootstrap min. js is running the request 2 times and hang until not refresh the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**[my ajax]
when i run the code the bootstrap.min.js will run but there two isssues comes in that 1. that is hit the request two time and 2. that after the 2 hit it will have to close the popup and hang the page until it refresh the page**

```
            function add_edit_party(){
                  var place_id = myFunction();
                  var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
                    var estimated_wait  = 0;
                     var no_sms = "";
                        var is_hd = 0;

          $j('.alert-danger').removeClass('show').addClass('hide');  
           if($j('#'+place_id+'_wl_phone').val()){
            phone_length = $j('#'+place_id+'_wl_phone').val().length;
            if (phone_length!=10){
             $j('#'+place_id+'_wl_phone').next().removeClass('hide').addClass('show');
                return false;
             }
           }

        if(!validateEmail($j('#'+place_id+'_wl_email').val())){
            $j('#'+place_id+'_wl_email').next().removeClass('hide').addClass('show');
            return false;
           }


         if($j('#'+place_id+'_wl_unknown_persons').val()==""){
            $j('#'+place_id+'_wl_unknown_persons').next().removeClass('hide').addClass('show');
            return false;
            }
        if($j('#'+place_id+'_wl_estimated_wait').val()=="" && $j('#serve_time').val() == "1"){
            $j('#'+place_id+'_wl_estimated_wait').next().removeClass('hide').addClass('show');
            return false;
         }
        if ($j('#serve_time').val() == "0"){
            estimated_wait = 0;
          }
         if ($j('#serve_time').val() == "1")


    estimated_wait =                                $j('#'+place_id+'_wl_estimated_wait').val();
            }

                 place_party_req_id = "";
                 if($j('#place_party_req_id').val()){
                 place_party_req_id = $j('#place_party_req_id').val();
                } 
            request_param = {  
                               place_id : place_id,
                                color_update_at: "3",
                                name : $j('#'+place_id+'_wl_name').val(),
                                notes : $j('#'+place_id+'_wl_notes').val(),
                                phone : "0"+$j('#'+place_id+'_wl_phone').val(),
                                email : $j('#'+place_id+'_wl_email').val(),
                                unknown_persons : $j('#'+place_id+'_party_size').val(),                     
                                size : $j('#'+place_id+'_party_size').val(),
                                 estimated_wait : estimated_wait,
                                  color_status: 3,
                                  party_request_id:       place_party_req_id,
                                authenticity_token : window._token
                            };
            $j(".loading").show();  
                var url='/add_party/'+place_id
                $j.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                async: false,
                data: request_param,
                dataType : 'json',
                success: function(result){
                if(result['party_id']){

                if($j('#place_party_req_id').val()){
                  edit_party_request($j('#place_party_req_id').val(),'accepted');
                  $j('#place_party_req_id').val("");
                }

                party_id = result['party_id'];
                if(estimated_wait=='0'){
                    seat_party(party_id);
                    return;
                }
                refresh_wl();
                setTimeout(function(){ jQuery(".loading").hide(); }, 600);
                $j('#myModal').modal('hide');
                $j('.nav-tabs a:first').tab('show'); 
              }
                            },
                     error: function(msg){
                    //alert("Something went wrong...");
             } 
        });
        return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

see whether you have added multiple js files in your `layout` file.It may be `application.js` or `jquery.js`.Many a times we add js file in the view as well as in the layout as well...

Moreover there can be a chance where any custom js in `application.js` will also having a duplicate file already included in `application.js` file.**Please check**